# QGIS Export Map to Image not to scale

Tags: qgis, export, mapping

When I do a Export Map to Image using QGIS then insert into C3D using Mapiinsert it does not come in to scale. I have successfully done this in the past so I'm not sure what is going on. Any ideas?

C3D coordinate system is set the same as QGIS.

Comment: Do you export georeference too? Which QGIS command do you use for  image export?

Comment: why did you expect it to? use a map layout with a scale bar